# Do you not use the t-table for hypothesis tests with n < 30? Has my professor made a mistakes in the provided answers?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, hypothesis-testing

Has my professor supplied incorrect solutions to this Hypothesis Testing excercise? (undergrad statistics class) I have my exam tomorrow, so help would be massively appreciated!

Here's the original question:

> Calculate the value of the test statistic, define the decision rule
> and conclude whether or not the null hypothesis is rejected for the
> given test. Use the information given with α=10%.
>
> Test H0: µ ≤ 6.3 vs H1: µ > 6.3, for σ is known. n=16, x=7.1, σ=1.25

The provided solution: (the part relevant to my confusion)

> 3. Define the rejection rule:

> If Z > u(1-α) -> reject H0   (For α = 10%, u(1-0.1) = u(0,9) = 1.29

From what I understand, if the sample size is n < 30, the student's t-table should be used. Even if the σ is known. So then, shouldn't the correct t-table value be 1.340606 (15df and p=0.1)
I have no idea where they are getting this value of 1.29 from? If you look at a right-tail t-table, the value for infinite is 1.282 for p=0.1, but I have no idea why they would use that?

Could someone please help me out?

Many thanks!

Comment: You use the $t$ distribution when you estimate the mean from the sample and then use this estimate to estimate the variance from the sample: the $t$ distribution takes account of the different effects of under- or over-estimating the variance.  But here you are told "σ is known. ..., σ=1.25" so you do not need to estimate $\sigma$ and so do not need the $t$ distribution